Mother gets involved with a crazy doomsday cult, only the cult turns out to be right
I am trying to find a religious horror movie I saw as a child:
A woman joins some sort of Christian sect, that believes the end of the world is near.
Somehow, either through her involvement with the cult, or when trying to leave it, her son gets killed, and she ends up in jail. Another cultist is in the same jail as well.
Then everything gets crazy. Turns out the cultist were correct after all, Armageddon is indeed at hand. The trumpets of the Revelation sound, the steel bars of the jail cells fall apart, while the other cultist sings "Hark! the Herald Angels Sing".
She escapes from jail together with a police officer on a motorcycle into a world filling with mist, chased by the riders of the Apocalypse, and then the world just fades to black.
The woman finds herself in a featureless black void, together with her dead son and the police officer. The son tries to convince her to come back to the faith and join him in paradise, but she says she cannot accept a god that would allow her son to die like he did, and that she would rater stay in hell forever. And that's it; the son goes to heaven (the officer too), she stays in hell, fade to black, roll credits.
I found the movie deeply disturbing as a child, and I would really like to find out how it came to be.
I think I saw it sometime between 1990 and 2000, on public television. I only saw the later half, so my recollection of the first part is conjecture.

Sounds like The Rapture with Mimi Rogers from 1991. From Wiki:

Sharon, a young Los Angeles woman, engages in a swinging, libidinous lifestyle. She comes into contact with a sect that advises her that the Rapture is imminent.

Every single detail you've described appears there (her dead child, the Rapture signalled by a trumpet while the mother's in jail, her and the police officer in purgatory and him ascending to heaven while she declines), expect for one thing: her dead child is a daughter, not a son. Here's the trailer.
