# Woman in computer taking over while head is in the fridge

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction, thriller

I am looking for a sci-fi movie title.

Plot(what I recall anyway):

A team of three computer scientists, two males (one on a wheelchair) and a female. I don't recall there name so let Adam be the male not on a wheelchair, Eve the female and John the last one on wheelchair. The story goes like this. They try to duplicate mice/mouse brain in a computer data storage and if I recall well it took like Terabytes to duplicate digitally the biological mouse brain (at some point by the way the mouse have offsprings in the computer). When they succeed, Eve decide to copy here mind in the computer (she, as I recall have epilepsy). Adam then takes Eve's head, who by the way is his mistress and put it in the freezer (DIY Cryogenics). Eve spent most of here time controlling the city or so and playing "big sister" watching every moves that Adam makes. While time goes by she gets more and more jealous. At some point she tries to shred either the hand of Adam's wife or his child. On day Adam's wife find the head in the freezer and goes berserk....in the end of the movie Eve tries so hard to destroy Adam's family but "dies" from epilepsy or something because her complete brain and brain "diseases" were duplicated digitally. The movie ends with John transferring his mind in the computer were he can leave the wheelchair and stand up and most importantly be the big brother, the master controller of the city or so.

I hope that rings any bell to someone. I think it's a TV movie (all I know is I saw it on TV).It's like sooo old I'm not even sure if my memories are exact. Before 2007 for sure and after 1996. I can't give a precise time.

Comment: From @walt's answer below I watched the clip which had this just a few recommended videos under it. Spoiler alert, it's a 5 minute synopsis of the movie: https://youtu.be/KYh3kUUdBU4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Host](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0144239/combined) (AKA Virtual Obsession) with Peter Gallagher and Mimi Rogers from 1998. Everything you've described (the young woman with the terminal brain illness, the married scientist freezing her head, her mind downloaded into a computer, her being able to control the city and mess with his life, wheelchair guy, lab rats etc. etc.) is all in there. [Here's a scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NYrSsp99Epo) with the protagonist and his wife.

Comment: Is it Mimi Rogers Day or something? ;) http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/21247/mother-gets-involved-with-a-crazy-doomsday-cult-only-the-cult-turns-out-to-be-r